# How to disable Chrome's omnibar history

Tags: google-chrome, browser-history

In Chrome (v69), I am seeking a way to prevent previous search terms from populating the omnibar dropdown.

For example, if I open Chrome and in the omnibar type out "test" (with quotes) and then hit enter, a search is conducted for "test". If I then open a new tab and type "t

two things happen:

1) the omnibar dropdown opens and shows a magnifying glass next to an entry that reads "test"

2) Chrome auto-completes my "t into "test"

I find auto-complete to heavily impede work flow, and I do not like the omnibar dropdown being populated with anything but bookmarks because it takes up too much screen real estate (covering up what I'm trying to see/read and also making it harder to spot the bookmark I want). So I would like to disable Chrome from recording my search terms and showing them in the omnibar.

I am using Debian Linux. So I have gone into .config > google-chrome > (profile) > and set History to read only. This solves the auto-complete annoyance problem. But it does not prevent "test" from appearing in the omnibar dropdown.

Does anyone know how to prevent "test" from appearing in the omnibar dropdown?